# Drawing a line in Swift using Spritekit

Tags: swift, xcode, lines

I'm trying to create a game where the user can draw, but I get an error at

```
path.addLine(to: <#T##CGPoint#>(x: line.end.x , y: line.end.y))
```

**"Cannot call value of non-function type "CGPoint"**.

I don't understand what this means.

Is this the correct way to enable the user to draw using touch if the error gets fixed?

Line Class

```
 import UIKit

    class Line {
        var start: CGPoint
        var end: CGPoint
        init (start _start: CGPoint, end _end: CGPoint) {
        start = _start
        end = _end
    }
}
```

GameScene:

```
    var lines: [Line] = []
    var lastTouch: CGPoint?
    var touchLocation: CGPoint!

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let firstTouch = touches.first {
            lastTouch = firstTouch.location(in: self)

        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let firstTouch = touches.first {
            //location where uitouch is moving
            touchLocation = firstTouch.location(in: self)
            //adds coordinates of lines to the line array
            lines.append(Line(start: lastTouch!, end: touchLocation))

            lastTouch = touchLocation

        }
    }

    func drawLines (firstPoint: CGPoint, lastPoint: CGPoint) {
        var path = CGMutablePath()
        for line in lines {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: line.start.x, y: line.start.y))
            path.addLine(to: <#T##CGPoint#>(x: line.end.x , y: line.end.y))

        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Apparently there are placeholder items in your code. Replace `<#T##CGPoint#>` by `CGPoint` (or rewrite the line from scratch).

Comment: You could also try this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/87899/make-simple-drawing-app-uikit-swift It is a very good tutorial on making a drawing app

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking the same way as you, but I figured out that what makes more sense in SpriteKit is to use ShapeNodes. I did it this way I show above. Note that both path and pathNode are shared variables from the scene!

```
func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        path.addLine(to: (touches.first?.location(in: self))!)
        pathNode.path = path
    }

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: (touches.first?.location(in: self))!)
        pathNode = SKShapeNode.init(path: path)
        pathNode.fillColor = .clear
        pathNode.strokeColor = .blue
        pathNode.lineWidth = 30
        addChild(pathNode)
    }
```